# Why this Angular form remains in invalid state after that I completly filled it?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am working on an Angular application using PrimeNG and I have the following problem with a form.

When I fill the form it remains in invalid state also if all the validators rules are satisfied.

This is my component HTML view:

```
<p-dialog header="Inserire un nuovo asset"
          maximizable="true"
          [(visible)]="displayNewAssetDialog"
          (onHide)="closeDialog()"
          position="top"
          [style]="{width: '50vw'}">

        <form [formGroup]="newAssetForm" id="addAssetForm" (ngSubmit)=saveNewAsset()>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Tipo asset</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                  <p-dropdown id="assetType"
                              [options]="assetTypeList" 
                              [(ngModel)]="selectedAssetTypeNg" 
                              formControlName="asset_type"
                              placeholder="Tipo asset" 
                              optionLabel="type" 
                              [showClear]="true">
                  </p-dropdown>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Modello</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input id="assetModel" formControlName="asset_model" type="text" pInputText />
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Assegnato a</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                  <p-dropdown id="employee_allocation"
                              [options]="employeesList$ | async" 
                              formControlName="employee_allocation"
                              placeholder="Impiegato" 
                              optionLabel="completeName" 
                              [showClear]="true">
                  </p-dropdown>
                </div>
              </div>
            -->
            

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Caratteristiche</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <textarea id="assetFeatures" 
                              class="p-inputtextarea"
                              formControlName="asset_features" 
                              [rows]="5" [cols]="30" 
                              pInputTextarea 
                              autoResize="autoResize">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Serial Number</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input id="serialNumber" formControlName="serial_number" type="text" pInputText />
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Data di consegna</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10" [ngClass]="{'ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched': isEmptyDate}">
                  <p-calendar [ngClass]="{'invalid-date': isValidDate}"
                              id="allocationDate" 
                              inputId="allocationDate"
                              formControlName="allocation_date"
                              >
                  </p-calendar>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>company</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input id="company" formControlName="company" type="text" pInputText />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Note</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <textarea id="notes" 
                              class="p-inputtextarea"
                              formControlName="notes" 
                              [rows]="5" [cols]="30" 
                              pInputTextarea 
                              autoResize="autoResize">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <p>Fattura/Provenienza</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <textarea id="invoice" 
                              class="p-inputtextarea"
                              formControlName="invoice" 
                              [rows]="5" [cols]="30" 
                              pInputTextarea 
                              autoResize="autoResize">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <p-footer>
                <span class="p-buttonset">
                  <button pButton 
                          type="submit"
                          label="Save" 
                          icon="pi pi-check"
                          [disabled]="!newAssetForm.valid">

                  </button>
                  <button pButton type="button" label="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" (click)="closeDialog()"></button>
              </span>
              </p-footer>

              <p>{{newAssetForm.valid}}</p>
              <p>{{newAssetForm.status | json }}</p>
              <p>{{newAssetForm.value | json }}</p>
        </form>
</p-dialog>
```

As you can see at the end of this file I have added some paragraphs tags containing form status information for debug purposes. You can see also that the submit buttons is disabled when the form is in invalid state.

Then this is the TypeScript code of my component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AssetService } from 'src/app/services/asset.service';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/services/employee.service';
import { Employee } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-add-form',
  templateUrl: './asset-add-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-add-form.component.scss']
})
export class AssetAddFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  displayNewAssetDialog: boolean;

  @Output()
  onDialogClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); 

  newAssetForm: FormGroup;
  
  assetTypeList: any[];
  selectedAssetTypeNg: any;
  isValidDate: boolean;
  isEmptyDate: true;
  loading: boolean = true;

  employeesList$:Observable<Employee[]>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private employeeService: EmployeeService,
              private assetService: AssetService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("AssetAddFormComponent INIT");

    this.assetTypeList = [
      {type: 'Notebook', code: 'NB' },
      {type: 'Notebook cliente', code: 'NB-C' },
      {type: 'Smartphone', code: 'SP' },
      {type: 'Drive', code: 'DRV' },
      {type: 'Licenza Office 2016', code: 'LO-2016' },
      {type: 'Licenza Office 2019', code: 'LO-2019' },
      {type: 'Licenza Office 2019 Professional', code: 'LO-2019-P' },
      {type: 'Licenza Office Plus 2019 Professional', code: 'LO-P-2019-P' },
      {type: 'RAM', code: 'RAM' },
      {type: 'Monitor', code: 'MON' },
      {type: 'Muletto', code: 'MUL' },
      {type: 'SIM', code: 'SIM' }
    ];

    this.loadEmployeesList().then(() => {this.loading = false;})

    this.newAssetForm = this.fb.group({
      asset_type: [null, [Validators.required]],
      asset_model: [null, [Validators.required]],
      //employee_allocation: [null],
      asset_features: [null, [Validators.required]],
      serial_number: [null, [Validators.required]],
      accessories: [null, [Validators.required]],
      allocation_date: [null, [Validators.required]],
      company: [null, [Validators.required]],
      notes: [null, [Validators.required]],
      invoice: [null, [Validators.required]]

    });
  }

  closeDialog() {
    console.log("CHILD COMPONENT closeDialog() START");
    this.onDialogClose.emit();
  }

  // Load the list of all the employees:
  async loadEmployeesList() {
    this.employeesList$ = await this.employeeService.getAllEmployees()
    console.log("employeesList$: ", this.employeesList$);
  }

  async saveNewAsset(){
    console.warn("saveNewAsset()",this.newAssetForm.value);    
    
    let parameters = {      
      firstName: this.newAssetForm.value.a,
      surname: this.newAssetForm.value.surname,      
      placeOfBirth: this.newAssetForm.value.placeOfBirth,
      socialSecurityCode: this.newAssetForm.value.socialSecurityCode,
      birthDate: this.newAssetForm.value.birthDate,
      companyEmail: this.newAssetForm.value.companyEmail,
      personalEmail: this.newAssetForm.value.personalEmail,     
      companyPhone: this.newAssetForm.value.companyPhone,  
      personalPhone: this.newAssetForm.value.personalPhone,  
      selectedEmployeeStatus: this.newAssetForm.value.selectedEmployeeStatus
    }

    if(this.newAssetForm.value.employee_allocation)
      parameters["employee_allocation"] = this.newAssetForm.value.employee_allocation;

    await this.assetService.saveAsset(parameters);
  }

}
```

The problem is that the after that I fill my form it still in invalid state. These are the information printed in the page by the previous debug paragraphs tags:

```
false

"INVALID"

{ "asset_type": { "type": "Notebook", "code": "NB" }, "asset_model": "ASUS X509JA-EJ026T ", "asset_features": "test1", "serial_number": "123xxx", "accessories": null, "allocation_date": "2020-12-26T23:00:00.000Z", "company": "Technology", "notes": "test2", "invoice": "test3" }
```

As you can see the form seems to be perfectly filled but it remains in invalid state.

This is a printscreen:

[image]

Why? What am I missing? What is wrong? How can I fix the problem? How can I check what is the exact error in the form? (I suppose that maybe using the deubugger I can see what are the fields going into error or I can print out these errors)

Comment: could you please provide a stackblitz workable demo to play around with? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you declared a form control named "accessories" e.g. (accessories: [null, [Validators.required]]) within your form group which is "required" however you didn't you use it in your html resulting in a permanent null value which is the default value that you provided.

What you can do is add another entry on your form like:

```
<div class="col-10">
   <input id="accessories" formControlName="accessories" type="text" pInputText />
</div>
```

then try to input some random value to test this.